# When my overloaded function can be called with const decoration?

Tags: c++, c++17

In the below code, I have two `begin()` functions. When is the second (`const`) version called? The reason I ask is because the STL vector has similar features, but it can be called correctly. I expect the line
`abc.begin();`
will call the `const` version of the `begin` function, but it didn't.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class test {
 public:
  test(vector<int> const &x) : a{x} {};
  test(vector<int> &x) : b{x} {};
  vector<int> begin() {
    cout << "int begin() is called" << endl;
    return b;
  }
  const vector<int> begin() const {
    cout << "int const begin() const is called" << endl;
    return a;
  }
 private:
  const vector<int> a;
  vector<int> b;
};

int main() {
  vector<int> b{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  const vector<int> a{4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
  test abc{a};
  test bcd{b};
  bcd.begin();
  abc.begin();
  return 0;
}
```

Code samples from STL vector

> ```
>     iterator begin() _NOEXCEPT
>         {return __make_iter(0);}
>     const_iterator begin() const _NOEXCEPT
>         {return __make_iter(0);}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Now I have figured it out. In order to use const member function, we need to declare the instance as constant, i.e.

> const test abc{a};

Comment: This is correct, a non-const object will always prefer to call a non-const function (but it cann call a const function, while a const object cannot call a non-const function). Furthermore if you only want to use a non-const object as const at one point, there is [`std::as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const). Also, std::vector has a const and a non-const overload for begin and additionally a const-only method cbegin that returns a const_iterator. Since there is no non-const overload, this will also be called for a non-const object.

Answer (score 0):

constant object used to call only const member function.